# how to display data from array of objects to a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, textbox

I have a users array having details of many users. I want to display details of the user logged in, in a textbox so that, I can add edit funtionality to it. How can I do it? Plzz help!

Comment: dude, please at least specify the language you are using.

Comment: html and javascript and the datas gets pushed into the array whenever any user registers.

Comment: Do you got any example to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a user data age having in an array like

```
var users =
 [
   { 
      'name':'Jhon',
      'age':'15'
   },
   { 
      'name':'Doe',
      'age':'56'
   }
 ];
```

If you wanna access the age of Doe, then you should probably know the index of that array, Doe is having the index 1 so,
    `document.getElementById('inputbox').value = users[1].age;`

Comment: I did like this, document.getElementById("input1").value=users[0].username; and its giving me error called 'cannot read property 'username' of undefined'.